# When are questions on heraldry on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I find the subject of heraldry fascinating, have answered a couple of questions here on this topic, and would quite like to ask some of my own questions.

I'm not quite sure, however, what the guidelines are on when heraldry questions fit within the scope of the site. For example, on [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/12483/), there is the comment "This is a question about genealogical heraldry, not history".

When are heraldry questions on- or off-topic? The particular question I'd like to ask at the moment relates to a crest I found on a coat of arms on a gravestone - how it might be described and whether any other examples of such a crest exist - but I'd quite like a more general answer for the future. Do these questions fall under the "cultures and historical practices" umbrella, or are these questions perhaps more suitable on the Genealogy and Family History stack?

Answer (score 6):

Good question. I'm not sure that we have a consensus on heraldry.

We have [many questions on heraldry](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heraldry), 95% of which have answers, so heraldry is not prima facia out of scope.

If the question is better answered by genealogical sources & methods, we defer to that site, but at least in my opinion (please insert non diamond disclaimer here), your question is in scope (and the fact that it has answers supports that opinion)

I wonder if the community has any guidance that can help to distinguish between questions best served by historical sources and methods and those best served by genealogical sources and methods? (I don't think they are disjoint, so there will be some overlap)

Answer (score 5):

Looking at it, that's just one user and the comment got no upvotes, while the question got 4 of them and 2 well-regarded answers. The Heraldry tag itself has 51 unclosed questions on it.

So it looks to me like that 1 comment was likely a trial balloon that floated off unregarded into the ether, never to be seen again.

In fact (switches tab...) there. Comment deleted. Problem solved. It was 8 years old, and clearly was no longer contributing to the improvement of the question.